# Is there a name or theory for this sieve characteristic?

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, prime-gaps, sieve-theory

In enumerating the primes algorithmically, the "completely naive" algorithm loops through every integer, the difference between succeeding candidates being 1. The first improvement is to "pre-identify" 2 as prime, and then only consider odd integers as candidates, the difference between succeeding candidates being 2. But this type of "improvement" can be extended indefinitely. The next step is "pre-identifying" both 2 and 3, and then only considering non-multiples of 2 and 3 as candidates. The differences between candidates forms a **period-2** sequence of repeating (2,4), i.e. 5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,... with difference sequence 2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4,2,... . The next step is to bring in 5 and additionally eliminate multiples of 5. The "difference sequence" takes on a **period of 8**, i.e. 4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6, repeated.

Is there a formula for calculating such difference sequences for any initial set of primes? Or even just a formula for calculating what the period of the difference sequence would be?

Comment: More or less you describe the idea of the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: mod 30 primes can only be 1,7,11,13,17,19,23,or 29 mod 30. look up wheel sieves.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Thanks! "Wheel" is the term. There is no "formula", you just have to compute the terms from 1 through the product of your primes that are relatively prime to all those primes, and then compute the differences if you want to use those. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892313/sieve-of-eratosthenes-with-wheel-factorization

Comment: you could also try Atkin's sieve, it eliminates most of this prior anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a wheel sieve as you found out in the comments. It actually can have a derivation but quite honestly not much point to it. Here's how it would go: $\gcd(a,b)=1\implies\gcd(a-b,b)=1$ that is, if $b$ is a remainder class mod $a$ that can have primes, so is $a-b$ . this is basically using the distributive property and factoring out. If we have to values that aren't relatively prime, then we can factor out a factor greater than 1 (and primes don't have factors greater than 1 that aren't themselves). So it turns out just pick all the relatively prime remainder classes. The number of relative primes to a number is always even, and the sequence will always be symmetric around the halfway point through the repeating part. You really want a formula for Euler's phi function: $$\varphi(n)=n\prod_{d\mid n,d\in \Bbb{P}}(1-{1 \over d})$$ this tells you how long the repeat part possibly goes on for. As to the values of differences, they'll typically be divisible by primes you eliminated.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite getting the derivation and the formula, because there are only 2 variables each (a&b, d&n). If I've got all the desired values for (2,3,5) and I want to generate the values for (2,3,5,7), what are a and b? (I get that n=210.)

Comment: well d are the divisors as that's what mid means. so that tells you how many there are. my point using the a and b variables is that by factoring out and distributive law a difference or sum of values that share a factor will  also have that factor. That's why we care that they don't share a factor.  in the n= 210 case we have divisors ( technically using the prime divisors doh). found my errors sorry about to fix it.

Comment: of 2,3,5, 7 so we have 210 * (1-1/7)*(1-1/5)*(1-1/3)*(1-1/2) = 180*(1-1/5)*(1-1/3)*(1-1/2)= 144*(1-1/3)*(1-1/2) = 96*(1-1/2) = 48  relatively prime values to 120 less than 120. each of which can create primes.

Comment: Interesting. So there **is** a formula, Euler's totient function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function, which in this case simplifies to $$\prod_{p\in set}(p-1)$$. And the symmetry of the sequence, and the fact that it always starts with 1, means that the "difference" sequence can be specified with just $$totient \over 2$$ values, the "connecting" value between turns of the difference wheel always being 2.

Comment: I'm still not getting how the "derivation" would go though, other than just sieving out multiples of the p's from the set 1...n/2.

Comment: yeah deriavation may be a wrong word.

Comment: I've gone ahead and analyzed the difference values for wheels generated by all primes up to 19. They typically include all even numbers, not just multiples of eliminated primes. Interestingly, the number of 2's is always equal to the number of 4's, 6's are always the most common, and the largest difference always occurs exactly twice.